# Is it possible to use an if clause in select / group by statement? Or another solution?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**Using SQLServer 2008**

I currently have a function that implements functionality as shown below (though there are variables in the function I just filled them in here to give a better idea of what the inputs might be like).

I was wondering if there is a way when you define the `@id` as null (currently used in the Coalesce on v.ID) to match everything as if you hadn't defined it in the select / group by clauses?

```
        SELECT
            'ALL' as GeogType,
            CAST(v.AdmissionOn as date) as dtAdmission,
            (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) as timeInterval,
            CAST((DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * (24/1) as nvarchar) + ':00' as fromTime,
            CAST((DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * (24/1) + (24/1) as nvarchar) + ':00' as toTime,    
            v.ID,
            COUNT(*) as nVisits
        FROM dbo.Table1 v INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 t ON v.FSLDU = t.FSLDU5
        WHERE v.AdmissionOn >= '01-01-2010' AND v.AdmissionOn < DATEADD(day,1,'02-01-2010') 
              AND v.ID = Coalesce(@id,ID)
        GROUP BY    
            CAST(v.AdmissionOn as date),
            (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1),
            (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * (24/1),
            (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * (24/1) + (24/1),
            v.ID    
        ORDER BY 2,3,4
```

It will return a result set similar to this when the `@id` is null:

```
ALL 2010-01-01  0   0:00    24:00   7   4
ALL 2010-01-01  0   0:00    24:00   4   54
ALL 2010-01-01  0   0:00    24:00   0   2303
ALL 2010-01-01  0   0:00    24:00   3   412
ALL 2010-01-01  0   0:00    24:00   6   57
ALL 2010-01-01  0   0:00    24:00   2   64
ALL 2010-01-01  0   0:00    24:00   5   5
ALL 2010-01-01  0   0:00    24:00   1   103
```

But I would like it to instead be:

```
ALL 2010-01-01  0   0:00    24:00   ?   3002
```

I am not sure what would go in the ? column, possibly something like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ?

Is this at all possible by something such as a case in the select / group by clause or a stored procedure that I do not know about? If not I can just create a new function but I was hoping there would be a way to do this by just inputting the `@id` as null.

Comment: Why do you use `(24/1)` instead of just `24`?

Comment: It is actually 24/@nIntervals but I replaced it for the example since I didn't want to define the variables I used when I could just fill in the values explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Group By to:

```
  GROUP BY CAST(v.AdmissionOn as date), 
     (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1), 
     (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * (24/1),
     (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * (24/1) + (24/1),  
     Case @Id When Null Then 0 Else Id End
```

What I had edited this to but will not work by itself is:

```
  GROUP BY CAST(v.AdmissionOn as date), 
     (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1), 
     (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * (24/1),
     (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * (24/1) + (24/1),  
     @Id
```

-- Either of these by themselves will causes an error because `Id` in the select statement is not in the Group By.  Either can be correctted by making the select consistent with the Group By

```
    SELECT 'ALL' as GeogType, CAST(v.AdmissionOn as date) as dtAdmission,
         (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) as timeInterval,  
         CAST((DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * 
              (24/1) as nvarchar) + ':00' as fromTime, 
         CAST((DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * 
              (24/1) + (24/1) as nvarchar) + ':00' as toTime, 
         Case @Id When Null Then 0 Else Id End Id,
         COUNT(*) as nVisits
    FROM dbo.Table1 v 
        JOIN dbo.Table2 t 
          ON v.FSLDU = t.FSLDU5
    WHERE v.AdmissionOn >= '01-01-2010' 
       AND v.AdmissionOn < DATEADD(day,1,'02-01-2010') 
       AND v.ID = Coalesce(@id,ID)      
    GROUP BY CAST(v.AdmissionOn as date), 
     (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1), 
     (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * (24/1),
     (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * (24/1) + (24/1),  
     Case @Id When Null Then 0 Else Id End
```

or

```
    SELECT 'ALL' as GeogType, CAST(v.AdmissionOn as date) as dtAdmission,
         (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) as timeInterval,  
         CAST((DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * 
              (24/1) as nvarchar) + ':00' as fromTime, 
         CAST((DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * 
              (24/1) + (24/1) as nvarchar) + ':00' as toTime, 
         @Id Id, COUNT(*) as nVisits
    FROM dbo.Table1 v 
        JOIN dbo.Table2 t 
          ON v.FSLDU = t.FSLDU5
    WHERE v.AdmissionOn >= '01-01-2010' 
       AND v.AdmissionOn < DATEADD(day,1,'02-01-2010') 
       AND v.ID = Coalesce(@id,ID)      
  GROUP BY CAST(v.AdmissionOn as date), 
     (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1), 
     (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * (24/1),
     (DATEPART(hour,CAST(AdmissionOn as time)))/(24/1) * (24/1) + (24/1),  
     @Id
```

Comment: Can you please change back to the previous edit so I may accept the answer? What finally worked for me was the `replace the two instances of v.ID with CASE WHEN @id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE v.ID END`

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY @id` instead of `GROUP BY v.id`, and replace `v.id` with `@id` in the SELECT statement.

Comment: On a side note, does `ORDER BY 2,3,4` work in SQL Server? I thought it did not?  (In that, is it ordering by fields 2, 3 and 4, or is it interpretting 2,3,4 just as constant integer values?)

Comment: Yes the order by works in sqlserver and I tried changing it to the @id but received the error message: 
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: You changed the `v.ID` instances to `@id` in the SELECT and the GROUP BY statements, and changed nothing else?

Comment: Yes, and I tried doing the same with the code provided (took it out of the function and tried to run it alone) and received the same message

Comment: Try Charles Bretana's suggestion (from before his edit): replace the two instances of `v.ID` with `CASE WHEN @id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE v.ID END`?  I can't see why it would help, but it would seem to satisfy the error message's requirement.

Comment: That actually worked thank you I didn't see that previous edit!